# Interting data column wise in Hive

Tags: hive

Is it possible to add data in Hive table column wise.

for example :
Let say I have a Hive table ( t1) like this.

```
  table:
   col1    col2
   1       20
   34      78
   67      89
```

I have some data separately like

```
   col3
   10
   20
   30
```

col3, you can consider it like an array or a table. What I want to achieve is something like this for same table t1:

```
  col1    col2  col3
   1       20    10
   34      78    20
   67      89    30
```

Is this possible in Hive? I saw syntax for adding new column by using ALTER statement but not able to find how can I add data as well.

Comment: No!!

Remember that, Hadoop supports append or overwrite; nor random access to update records.

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5317

Comment: I agree with you @Dudu Markovitz; but, that's in 0.14 or later versions.
taken care of.
But in that case as well, the question cant be resolved. - Balance between performance and outcome has to be

Comment: **(1)** 0.14 was released more than 2.5 years ago, on November 2014 **(2)** It does not solve the OP issue because UPDATE does not support sub-queries

Comment: OP, what is your motivation here?